# Combining data and inserting to database with a one-to-one relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony3.x

I have a problem with inserting data to the database with a one-to-one relationship. The problem is that I can not use FormBuilder. Because the data comes from the form js.
User selects the status field from the drop-down list.Now I would like insert returned id to entity orders.

**Status Entity:**

```
/**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $status;
```

**Order Entity:**

```
/**
     * @var int
     *
     *  @OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Status", fetch="EAGER",cascade={"persist"})
     * @JoinColumn(name="Status_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $Status;
```

**Service:**

```
$order=new Orders();
        $status=new GlobalStatus();
        $status->getId(1);
        $order->setGlobalStatus($status);

        $this->em->persist($order);
        $this->em->flush();
```

Then doctrine tries to add data to the Status table. If I do not try to create a Status instance, I get an error :(
Can someone advise me how to add this data?

Comment: Is it significant for you to have the owning side in `Order` entity?

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski I don't know if I understood you well. Unfortunately, I can not give up js form. Because data for drop lists is downloaded by ajax. And I can not do this with the formbuilder :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Status Entity**

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var Order
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Order")
 */
protected $order;
```

**Order Entity:**

```
/**
 * @var Status
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=30)
 */
protected $status;
```

**Your service:**

```
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @param Status $status
     */
    public function bar(Status $status)
    {
        if (!$status instanceof Status) {
            return;
        }

        $order = new Order(); //Should be singular
        $order->setStatus($status); //If it's `global` consider use enumType instead

        $this->em->persist($order);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

How to want you to fetch **Form Data** and bind it to `Status` entity?

Comment: I would like to send the entire request form to the service.Because this data will still be processed in the service.

Comment: Maybe I'm completely wrong about the subject :( In the location table are located defined storage spaces ( warehouse 1, warehouse 2 , et cetera). I would like to order table insert id storage space. It is important that the order could have only one storage location.
You can advise me what relationship to use in this case?

Comment: @grda `OneToOne` relationship to ensure that the order can have only one storage location.

Comment: @grda You want to send the entire request form to the service, and bind it to an entity - seems ok for me. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Assumptions have changed, but thank you very much for your help. With the transfer of the request to the service I can handle it